# Replace all occurrence of double dash (--) with —, but not inside attributes or comments

Tags: php, html-parsing

```
some text here
<span class="my--class-name--here" id="some--id">some -- text--here</span> 
test text--here
<div class="another--class-name">test --test</div>
<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
```

For the above content, I want some help in writing code to replace all occurrence of double dash (`--`) with `&mdash;`.

But, it should not replace the double dash for any attributes inside the html elements. For e.g., the double dash in the class name (`my--class-name--here`) and id name (`id="some--id"`) should not replaced.
And, also it should not replace double dash in `<!--[if IE 9]>` and `<![endif]-->`

Comment: So basically all the `--` outside of html tags?

Comment: I've removed the requirement that this be done with a regex. Regexes are not a great tool for this, and there's no reason to limit the solution to a regex.

Comment: @hwnd yes all -- outside of html tags. but it should not replace the line comments line <!-- xyz -->

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting a one-liner to replace outside of `<` and `>`, you can use the following.

```
$html = preg_replace('~<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|--~', '—', $html);
```

The idea is to skip any content that is located between an opening and closing bracket character.

On the left side of the alternation operator we match the subpattern we do not want. Making it fail and forcing the regular expression engine to not retry the substring using backtracking control verbs.

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/201333)

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead to match `--` which was not inside any html tags.

```
--(?![^><]*>)
```

Replace the matched `--` with `—`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lJ1fL0/2)

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
some text here
<span class="my--class-name--here" id="some--id">some -- text--here</span> 
test text--here
<div class="another--class-name">test --test</div>
<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
EOT;
echo preg_replace('~--(?![^><]*>)~', '—', $string);
?>
```

Output:

```
some text here
<span class="my--class-name--here" id="some--id">some — text—here</span> 
test text—here
<div class="another--class-name">test —test</div>
<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: I've edited the html text `<span class="my--class-name--here" id="some--id">` to include some more attributes like `id="some--id"`. Can you please check for that too.

Comment: yep. did you want o replace `--` in the id part? ie, in `id="some--id"`

Comment: no, it should not replace anything inside the html tag.

Comment: then edit your question ... IT seems like you don't want to replace `--`, only in the class.

Comment: OPs question is clear, hence why I submitted my answer as I did. OP commented `@hwnd yes all -- outside of html tags`

Comment: @hwnd But, the double dash in the class name (e.g., my--class-name--here) should not replaced. And, also it should not replace double dash in <!--[if IE 9]> and <![endif]--> Why he mention this specifically?